# Visualize log fields in using kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana

I have logs of this format in kibana

```
[2020-05-22 10:26:00,803: WARNING/MainProcess] Q Status: ac: 16, sc: 715, res: 5039 reg: 6, sum: 5770
[2020-05-22 10:25:39,811: WARNING/MainProcess] Q Status: ac: 16, sc: 715, res: 5042 reg: 6, sum: 5773
[2020-05-22 10:25:18,900: WARNING/MainProcess] Q Status: ac: 16, sc: 715, res: 5048 reg: 6, sum: 5779
[2020-05-22 10:24:58,101: WARNING/MainProcess] Q Status: ac: 16, sc: 715, res: 5054 reg: 6, sum: 5785
[2020-05-22 10:24:37,401: WARNING/MainProcess] Q Status: ac: 16, sc: 715, res: 5056 reg: 6, sum: 5787
[2020-05-22 10:24:16,601: WARNING/MainProcess] Q Status: ac: 16, sc: 715, res: 5060 reg: 6, sum: 5791
[2020-05-22 10:23:55,413: WARNING/MainProcess] Q Status: ac: 16, sc: 715, res: 5066 reg: 6, sum: 5797
[2020-05-22 10:23:34,401: WARNING/MainProcess] Q Status: ac: 16, sc: 715, res: 5069 reg: 6, sum: 5800
[2020-05-22 10:23:13,600: WARNING/MainProcess] Q Status: ac: 16, sc: 715, res: 5076 reg: 6, sum: 5807
[2020-05-22 10:22:52,727: WARNING/MainProcess] Q Status: ac: 16, sc: 715, res: 5079 reg: 6, sum: 5810
```

Is it possible to plot a time-series in kibana of the `sum` field. Maybe using regex extraction